# Running a jar of SWT/JFace project on the other Computers

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, project

I am creating a SWT/JFace project and exporting as executable jar. But this jar is not working on the other computers. When use double clicks the jar nothing happens. I am sure that other user has JRE installed.

I think problem is the Referanced Libraries. Beause near the libraries its written C:\Users\Turgut - İhracat.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321.jar

Any helps will be apriciated..

Answer (score 0):

A **plain SWT Java application** requires at least

- the **platform independent `org.eclipse.swt_<version>.jar`** and
- the **platform dependent `org.eclipse.swt.<platform>_<version>.jar`** of the same version.

The platform dependent JAR contains the native SWT library and must correspond to the operating system and JRE, e. g. for Windows and a 64 bit JRE the current JAR is `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar` (for macOS X see also *[Deploying SWT Applications on Mac OS X](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/)*.).

For **JFace** the JARs

- **`org.eclipse.jface_<version>.jar`**,
- **`org.eclipse.equinox.common_<version>.jar`** and
- **`org.eclipse.core.commands_<version>.jar`**.

are required in addition (see *[Using JFace outside the Eclipse platform](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Using_JFace_outside_the_Eclipse_platform)*).

The `org.eclipse.osgi` JAR and other JARs are only required for [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)-based applications. SWT/JFace works in both plain Java and OSGi applications.